# Accessing jq arrays with bash attribute

Tags: bash, jq

Is it  possible to access json array with bash attributes?

JSON example:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "John"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Doe"
    },
    ...
}
```

Bash example, something like this:

```
count=0
id=$(cat example.json | jq -r '.data[$count].id')
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply with `--argjson` option which will consider `$cnt` variable as already *JSON*-encoded value:

```
$ cnt=0
$ jq --argjson cnt "$cnt" '.data[$cnt]' file.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John"
}
```

> **`--argjson name JSON-text`**:
>
> This option passes a JSON-encoded value to the jq program as a
> predefined variable. If you run jq with `--argjson foo 123`, then
> `$foo` is available in the program and has the value `123`

Answer (score 3):

Use [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes) instead of single to allow variable interpolation:

```
jq -r ".data[$count].id" example.json
```